# How to get the index of the ListBox item selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

Sorry to ask a silly question.
The behavior of my WPF UI is driving me crazy.
I would like to be able to select the single items in a ListBox that displays a list of strings.

```
    <ListBox x:Name="CTnames" Grid.Column="80" Grid.Row="5" 
     Height="700" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData}" 
     scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
     scrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="20,10,560,100" 
     Grid.ColumnSpan="16" SelectionMode="Single" Selected="CTnames_Selected" />
```

If I list the properties of the ListBox and click on the Event symbol (lightning bolt) I can see that "Selected" is a ListBox event. I double click on it and Visual Studio generates the method "CTnames_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)"
Inside such a method I would like to get the index of the selected string in the ListBox.

```
public int CTindex { get; set; }

private void CTnames_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   CTindex = CTnames.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Unluckily, the compiler returns the following error in the XAML file at the line corresponding to the definition of the ListBox:

"**Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1061  'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no accessible extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  WPFUI   C:\Users\mauram\Desktop\WPFDemo_Dapper\WPFUI\MainWindow.xaml    142**"

I cannot understand such an error because "Selected" is listed by Visual Studio as a ListBox event.

My goal is to get the index of the selected item and use it to get another list of strings that will be displayed in another ListBox.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It is unclear which documentation you are referring to, but the WPF ListBox does not have a Selected event. You would bind its SelectedIndex, SelectedItem or SelectedValue property, the latter in conjunction with SelectedValuePath. Or attach a handler to its SelectionChanged event. Here is the online documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2022. I select ListBox "properties".  "Selected" is one of the properties. VS generates the method corresponding to a property by selecting the lightning bolt icon and then double-clicking on the property name. It also modifies accordingly the control definition. In fact,  "Selected="CTnames_Selected" is added by VS to the ListBox definition in the .xaml file.  The corresponding method "private void CTnames_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" is added in the .cs file. So why then the C# compiler states that ListBox does not have a "Selected" event?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that gives index of selected item in ListBox.
In Mainwindow.Xaml file

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

---

In MainWindow.cs flie --

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Names = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Tom", "ken","Jen" };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
          
        }

        private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Selected Index is" + listBox.SelectedIndex);

            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listBox.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, by choosing the SelectionChangedEvent it is possible to get access to the index and the content of the selected item. What is not clear to me is why the compiler does not recognize the "Selected" event. I did not make it up. It is shown in the events list for the ListBox. Any clue?